# Getting GeoJSON data in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

```
L.Control.fileLayerLoad({
    fitBounds: true,
    layerOptions: {
        style: style,
        pointToLayer:function (data, latlng) {debugger;
            return L.circleMarker(
            latlng,
            { style: style }
            );
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            console.log("FEATURE",feature,"LAYER",layer);
            geojsonLayer = layer // 
        }
    }

}).addTo(map);
```

I am trying to collect geojson data and use it. this function gives correct results for line and polygon. But when I use point data it gets stuck.

Comment: Does your browser's console display any error messages?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, it gives sth like that;   FEATURE Object LAYER e